# Listview not updating

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple listview that is being populated by user input. The user clicks a floating button that displays a dialog box for their information before clicking an `OK` button. When the button is clicked I would like the list to be updated. I have been using `notifyDataSetChanged()` but that isnt working. What is updating is when I leave the activity and re enter it again, but obviously this is not what I want to have to do.

Can someone look at my code to see where I am going wrong?

**MyCursorAdapter**

```
        db.open();

    db.getAllRecipes();

    Cursor cursor = db.getAllItems();

    //String[] columns = new String[] {db.KEY_NAME, db.KEY_CODE, db.KEY_ROWID};
    String[] columns = new String[] {db.KEY_ITEM_NAME};

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.ingredientName};

    final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row4, cursor, columns, to, 0);
```

**List and Button Listener**

```
        final ListView shoppingList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shoppingList);
    shoppingList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    FloatingActionButton filterButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.filterButton);
    filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // custom ingredient_dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.shopping_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Add Item");

            final EditText item = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.item);

            Spinner measurement = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.measurement);

            Spinner unit = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.unit);

            Button dialogButtonOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom ingredient_dialog
            dialogButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String newItem = item.getText().toString();
                    db.open();
                    db.insertItem(newItem);
                    myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Comment: can you update the code to show how you are initializing MyCustomAdapter instance ?

Comment: Just updated it there

Answer (score 0):

On the click of button you are inserting the item to database but nowhere you are repopulating the adapter. That's why listview is not being updated.

You need to get data from database once you update it and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

In short adapter creation code need to be called after you insert the data to your database. Do this and it's done.

Comment: Ok thank you, is there a quick way that I could update my simple cursor once the user has entered the data?

Comment: @JJSmith: I don't think there is any simpler way. But also I am not 100% sure. Why don't you put the adapter creation code in a method and call the same method here again.